# Asp ajaxtoolkit combobox can not type in Firefox

Tags: asp.net, ajax

Asp ajaxtoolkit combobox is not working in Firefox. I can not type in combobox in Firefox.but works fine in IE.

```
<ajaxToolkit:ComboBox ID="ComboBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="False" DropDownStyle="DropDownList" AutoCompleteMode="SuggestAppend" CaseSensitive="False" CssClass="" ItemInsertLocation="Append" >
   <asp:ListItem>Apple</asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem>Orange</asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem>banana</asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem>Mango</asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
</ajaxToolkit:ComboBox>
```

Comment: Why, Call Microsoft support, I am sure they will answer you because Microsoft is also behind Asp ajaxtoolkit as IE. Can you make it clear what you are trying to get worked or show some better detail about your problem.

Comment: <ajaxToolkit:ComboBox ID="ComboBox1" runat="server"
     AutoPostBack="False"
     DropDownStyle="DropDownList"
     AutoCompleteMode="SuggestAppend"
     CaseSensitive="False"
     CssClass=""
     ItemInsertLocation="Append" > 
<asp:ListItem>Apple</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Orange</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>banana</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Mango</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
</ajaxToolkit:ComboBox>


I am using this but I can not type in combobox in firefox

Answer (score 1):

add MaxLength="50" or your requirement. it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

DropDownStyle="DropDownList" prevents typing